# Euler product for L-series of a modular form

Tags: modular-forms, euler-product

I might not be seeing the wood for all the trees in what follows.

If $f(z)=\sum_{n}a_{n}z^{-n}$ is a Hecke eigenform, the coefficients $a_{n}$ satisfy the relation
$$a_{p^{j}}=a_{p^{j-1}}a_{p}-pa_{p^{j-2}}$$
if $p$ is a prime and
$$a_{mn}=a_{m}a_{n}$$
if $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

So far, so good. How does this relation imply the summation formula
$$\sum_{j}a_{p^{j}}p^{-js}=\frac{1}{1-a_{p}p^{-s}+p^{1-2s}}\text{?}$$

Comment: Once you know $a_1=1$ and $a_p$ you know all $a_{p^j}$. Then it suffices to check the coefficients of $\frac{1}{1-a_{p}p^{-s}+p^{1-2s}}$ obey this relation.

Comment: All issues of convergence set aside, look at $b_j=a_{p^j}$ and its recurrence relation, and take formally $X=p^{-s}$.

Comment: Also for $\Gamma_0(N)$ modular forms, eigenform means eigenfunction of the Hecke operators $T_n, \gcd(n,N)=1$ we need the newforms things to find $\sum_n a_n n^{-s} = (\sum_{d |N} c_d d^{-s}) \prod_p \frac{1}{1-a_{p}p^{-s}+1_{p \nmid N} p^{1-2s}}$

Comment: Thank you all for these comments, but that is precisely the step where I'm not seeing the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it now. Set $x=p^{-j}$ and expand the fraction into a Taylor series; the recurrence relation for the coefficients follows easily. I should have figured that one out myself.